# How do I get a subclass to use a parent class' protected methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass, protected

I'm writing a front controller servlet class for webapps. The front controller is designed to differentiate between three basic cases:

1. File request (calling a `FileRequestHandler` instance)
2. Data request (calling a `DataRequestHandler` instance)
3. Servlet request (calling a `ServletRequestHandler` instance)

For testing I wanted to use Tomcat's `DefaultServlet` ([javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29),[source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java.html)) to serve files but I cannot get it to work. The problem is that even though my `FileRequestHandler` class should properly extend the `DefaultServlet` I cannot access its protected methods (specifically `doGet` for handling GET requests). The classes are in different packages btw.

---

**Code:**

```
public class FileRequestHandler extends DefaultServlet {

// fields

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// methods

    public void setResponse(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response, URI uri) 
            throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
                                                                                                                                    /* DEBUG */try {
            System.out.println("(!!) doGet >> " + DefaultServlet.class.getMethod("doGet",new Class[]{HttpServletRequest.class,HttpServletResponse.class}) ) ;
            doGet(request,response) ;
                                                                                                                                    /* DEBUG */}
                                                                                                                                    /* DEBUG */catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("(!) " + this.getClass( ).getName( ) + " >> buildResponse >> " + e.toString( ) ) ; }
    }

 }
```

---

**Stack trace:**

(part leading up to the NullPointer)

> at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:398)
>       at org.pulse.web.FileRequestHandler.buildResponse(FileRequestHandler.java:39)

---

**Update:**

I maybe have to clarify that the front controller servlet will intercept all HttpRequests, (`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` in web.xml) to the effect that DefaultServlet instantiated by the servlet container will not receive any requests, as far as I can tell.
I have now explicitely called `DefaultServlet#init` in the front controller class:

```
 FileRequestHandler fileRequestHandler = new FileRequestHandler( ) ;
 fileRequestHandler.init( ) ;
```

Now I end up with a 404 Servlet is not available.

**Update2:** The problem -- as turns out -- actually is a follow-up problem with inadequate use of the extended class rather than a direct problem with inheritance.

---

<strike>The post to the Log which I added to detect the problem's root will provoke a `NoSuchMethodException`.</strike>. If I omit it I'll get a `NullPointerException`.

It looks ever so simple. Still I can't get it to work the way I want it to. Any ideas,  suggestions or insights?

TIA,

FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.getMethod` returns *public* methods - there's no such *public* method, hence the exception. You can use `getDeclaredMethod` to get non-public methods.

It's not clear why you were getting a `NullPointerException` when you tried it without the logging - if you can post a fuller stack trace, it may be clearer.

EDIT: Judging by the [source code for DefaultServlet](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_32/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java) it looks like this is the line throwing the exception:

```
CacheEntry cacheEntry = resources.lookupCache(path);
```

That doesn't make much sense though, as `init()` should have thrown an exception in that case... is there anything else reporting an error in your logs?

Comment: Updated my post. Neither `request` nor `response` are null btw.

Comment: @FK82: What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: @John Skeet: Do I need to explicitely call `init` maybe? According to the docs (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) the Servlet container would usually do that.

Comment: @FK82: You shouldn't need to, no. That should be called automatically as part of the servlet lifecycle. Anything interesting in your logs before this exception?

Comment: @ John Skeet: Nothing in particular the stack trace up to the NullPointer is the expected chain of method calls. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: @FK82: I don't see an update since my last comment... how are you running this? What's calling setResponse?

Comment: @ John Skeet: Sorry, just now updated my post. `FileRequestHandler#setResponse` is getting called by the front controller servlet if the URL pattern indicates a file.

Comment: @FK82: So are you creating the instance of `FileRequestHandler` yourself? If so, the container *won't* have called `init()` - it only initializes servlets which it manages.

Comment: @ John Skeet: Exactly. I guess that's the problem at stake here, isn't it?

Comment: @FK82: Yes. Basically you shouldn't be instantiating servlets yourself. You can potentially redirect to another servlet, either externally or internally, or you may want to use an MVC style container instead of raw servlets.

Comment: @ John Skeet: I see. So, I should use `ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher` and redirect to `DefaultServlet` instead, right?

Comment: @FK82: I'm unsure, to be honest - it's a while since I've handled servlets directly. But yes, that may well do it.

Comment: @ John Skeet: guess I'll have to do more research then. Thanks for your help for the time being! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything special in order to call a protected method from the superclass.  In fact, since you haven't overridden `doGet()` in your servlet, its `doGet()` method should literally be the superclass method.  You shouldn't have to do anything special, beyond calling it normally, like:

```
public void setResponse(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response, URI uri) 
        throws IOException, ServletException  {

        doGet(request,response) ;
}
```

If you want you can replace `doGet(request,response)` with `super.doGet(request,response)`, but it will make no difference in this case because you have not overridden `doGet()` in your subclass.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. :-)